# Get the SQL version on the machine running my app

Tags: c#, sql, version, local

I'm writing in c# (.Net 3.5) and I would like to get the version of the SQL installed in the local machine. It means I don't have a connection string which includes address\username\password, I just need the version of the SQL on the local machine without retrieving data from the databases etc.

I tried to use "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.**Wmi**", but it seems it **depends on the SQL version**.

Any ideas?
Thanks, KM

EDIT:
Some notes,

- I don't want to try/catch each DLL
  "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi" (There is different DLL to
  different SQL version)
- The only detail I need is the SQL version of the machine I'm
  running on.
- I don't have connection string / user name / password

Comment: You can use WMI for SQL SERVER 2005 and above, but SQL Server 2000 not discoverable by WMI.

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` but it has only the following classes: `Agent`, `Broker` and `Mail`. I don't see the `Wmi`. I read at MSDN that I probably need to add the dll `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll` but it is not listed in .NET references.

Comment: For 2000 you can't use `Smo`, it hasn't `Smo` it has `Dmo`. If you need resolve your problem only for 2005 and above i can help you, but for 2000 i don't know how it's done.

Comment: Assuming I need it for 2005 and above, The problem is that reference `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` is specific to SQL version. It means I need to add DDLs for all versions and appropriate wrappers to each DLL. I need a way to check the SQL version of the local machine I'm running on without trying (and catching) each DLL.

Comment: You don't need to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` you can solve your problem using `System.Management` namespace.

Comment: `Smo` and `Wmi` are included in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` and not in `System.Management`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10" -Class SqlServiceAdvancedProperty -ComputerName <SERVERNAME> | Format-Table ServiceName, PropertyName, PropertyNumValue, PropertyStrValue -AutoSize
```

Use `root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10` namespace for sql server 2008 and above and `root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement` for 2005 instead.

You can achieve this result from .net using `System.Management` namespace.

**UPDATE**

You can use this to detect which kind of SQL Server WMI providers are installed.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumCorrectWmiNameSpace()
{
    const string WMI_NAMESPACE_TO_USE = @"root\Microsoft\sqlserver";
    try
    {
        ManagementClass nsClass =
            new ManagementClass(
                new ManagementScope(WMI_NAMESPACE_TO_USE),
                new ManagementPath("__namespace"),
                null);

        return nsClass
            .GetInstances()
            .Cast<ManagementObject>()
            .Where(m => m["Name"].ToString().StartsWith("ComputerManagement"))
            .Select(ns => WMI_NAMESPACE_TO_USE + "\\" + ns["Name"].ToString());
    }
    catch (ManagementException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception = " + e.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is the SQL version installed (2008 nor 2005). That's exactly what I need. So I can't decide which root to use.

Comment: Yes. I can't invoke the `Cast`. I got the following error: `'System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You are missing a using directive or an assembly reference. `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: **Thanks. It's working.** It seems I need a new requirement for the client: install power shell SDK.
I will close the question in a few days in case someone has a solution which not requires installing power shell SDK.

Comment: You don't need to install powershell SDK. System.Management.dll is .net assembly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get SQL Server Insance that installed on your machine you can use this code :

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi;
....

ManagedComputer mc = new ManagedComputer();

foreach (ServerInstance si in mc.ServerInstances)
{
     Console.WriteLine("The installed instance name is " + si.Name);
}
```

or if you want to get SQL Server Version you can use this code :

```
try
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(sqlConnection));

    switch (server.Information.Version.Major)
    {
      case 8:
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2000");
        break;
      case 9:
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2005");
        break;
      case 10:
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server 2008");
                break;
      default:
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SQL Server {0}", server.Information.Version.Major.ToString())); 
        break;   
    }
}
catch (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to server",
        "Invalid Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}
```

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` but it has only the following classes: `Agent`, `Broker` and `Mail`. I don't see the `Wmi`. I read at MSDN that I probably need to add the dll `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll` but it is not listed in .NET references

Comment: @kernelMode you must add this reference : Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement

Comment: The problem is that reference `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement` is specific to SQL version. It means I need to add DDLs for all versions and appropriate wrappers to each DLL. I need a way to check the SQL version of the local machine I'm running on without trying (and catching) each DLL.